# updating row not working ,save button duplicating rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Screenshot of the screen

[image]

> Notice: Undefined index: cur_id1 in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\setup\manage_position_sub.php on line 87
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'and'. (severity 15) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on
>   line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cur_id1 in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\setup\manage_position_sub.php on line 89
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'and'. (severity 15) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on
>   line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cur_id1 in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\setup\manage_position_sub.php on line 92
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'and'. (severity 15) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on
>   line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cur_id1 in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\setup\manage_position_sub.php on line 94
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'and'. (severity 15) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on line 15
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\includes\connecto.php on
>   line 15
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cur_id1 in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache2.2\htdocs\hr\setup\manage_position_sub.php on line 96

Now the problem is when I click save button for the update query its just duplicating the last row. When inserting there is no problem. `php` Code is shown below. If needed I will post full code, any one familiar with `php` and `mysql` please check through it. Hope you guys understand the question. please check through it.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">

    <?php 
    header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1256");
    include_once('../includes/header_config.php');
    $sorting=' order by depe asc';
    if (isset($_POST['field']))
    {
    if ($_POST['field'] != '')
    {
    $sorting=' order by '.$_POST['field'];
    }
    else
    {
    $sorting=' ';
    }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    //delete
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']==3) ) {
    $sql="delete from hr_position where code=".$_POST['delid'];
    $qry = DB_query($sql,$db);
    $sql="delete from listsvalues where listid=40 and id=".$_POST['delid'];
    $qry = DB_query($sql,$db);
    $sql = "delete from hrnodes  where contactid = '".$_POST['delid']."' and userid=15";
    $result2= DB_query($sql,$db);
    }
    ?>


    <?php
    //insert 

    if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']==2) ) {
    if ($_POST['invoicebreakdown']=='' || $_POST['invoicebreakdown']==0) $invoice_breakdown = 1; else $invoice_breakdown = $_POST['invoicebreakdown'];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $invoice_breakdown; $i++){
    if (isset($_POST['field1'.$i]) ) {
    if(isset($_POST['cur_id_'.$i]) && $_POST['cur_id_'.$i]!='') $cur_id = $_POST['cur_id_'.$i]; else $cur_id ='';
    if($cur_id=='') {
            $sql="select max(code) as mx from hr_position";
            $qry = DB_query($sql,$db);
            if ($res = DB_fetch_array($qry))
            {
                if ($res['mx']==NULL)
                {

                    $newid= 1;
                }
                else
                    {
                    $i =(int) $res['mx'];
                    $i=++$i;
                    $newid= $i;
                    }
            }       

    echo $sql = "insert into hr_position (code,descr,lang) values (".$newid.",'".$_POST['field1'.$i]."',0)";
    $result= DB_query($sql,$db);
    echo $sql = "insert into listsvalues (id,listid,userid,descr,lang,seq) values (".$newid.",40,-1,'".$_POST['field1'.$i]."',0,".$newid.")";
    $result= DB_query($sql,$db);
    echo $sql = "insert into hr_position (code,descr,lang) values (".$newid.",'".$_POST['field2'.$i]."',1)";
    $result= DB_query($sql,$db);
    echo $sql = "insert into listsvalues (id,listid,userid,descr,lang,seq) values (".$newid.",40,-1,'".$_POST['field2'.$i]."',2,".$newid.")";
    $result= DB_query($sql,$db);
    echo $sql = "insert into hr_position (code,descr,lang) values (".$newid.",'".$_POST['field3'.$i]."',2)";
    $result= DB_query($sql,$db);
    echo $sql = "insert into listsvalues (id,listid,userid,descr,lang,seq) values (".$newid.",40,-1,'".$_POST['field3'.$i]."',1,".$newid.")";
    $result= DB_query($sql,$db);

    $sql = "select max(id) as mx from hrnodes ";
    $result1= DB_query($sql,$db);
    $newid1 = DB_fetch_array($result1);
    $nwd = $newid1['mx']+1;
    if ($_SESSION['lang']==0) {$name = $_POST['field1'.$i];} else if ($_SESSION['lang']==1) {$name = $_POST['field2'.$i];} else {$name = $_POST['field3'.$i];}
    $sql = "insert into hrnodes (id,userid,title,position,parentid,contactid,acyear) VALUES 
    ('".$nwd."','15','".$name."','0','2','".$newid."','')";
    $result2= DB_query($sql,$db);

    }
    else
    {
    $sql = "update hr_position set descr='".$_POST['field1'.$i]."' where code =".$_POST['cur_id'.$i]." and lang = 0";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update listsvalues set descr='".$_POST['field1'.$i]."' where listid=40 and id =".$_POST['cur_id'.$i]." and lang = 0";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "update hr_position set descr='".$_POST['field2'.$i]."' where code =".$_POST['cur_id'.$i]." and lang = 2";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update listsvalues set descr='".$_POST['field2'.$i]."' where listid=40 and id =".$_POST['cur_id'.$i]." and lang = 2";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update hr_position set descr='".$_POST['field3'.$i]."' where code =".$_POST['cur_id'.$i]." and lang = 1";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update listsvalues set descr='".$_POST['field3'.$i]."' where listid=40 and id  =".$_POST['cur_id'.$i]." and lang = 1";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);


if ($_SESSION['lang']==0) {$name = $_POST['field1'.$i];} else if ($_SESSION['lang']==1) {$name = $_POST['field2'.$i];} else {$name = $_POST['field3'.$i];}

$sql = "update hrnodes set title='".$name."' where  contactid = '".$_POST['cur_id'.$i]."' and userid=15";
$result2= DB_query($sql,$db);
    }
    }
    }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    if(!isset($_POST['breakdown'])) $_POST['breakdown']=0;
    $sql = "SELECT    distinct hr_position.code, hr_position.descr AS depe, hr_position_1.descr AS depf, hr_position_2.descr AS depa
    FROM         hr_position INNER JOIN
                          hr_position hr_position_1 ON hr_position.code = hr_position_1.code INNER JOIN
                          hr_position hr_position_2 ON hr_position_1.code = hr_position_2.code 
    WHERE   hr_position.code<>-1 and  (hr_position.lang = 0) AND (hr_position_2.lang = 2) AND (hr_position_1.lang = 1)".$sorting;

    $result= DB_query($sql,$db);
    $num_rows = DB_num_rows($result);
    $tot = $_POST['breakdown']+$num_rows;
    ?>


    <input type="hidden" name="amttype" value="" id="amttype">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoicebreakdown" value="<?php echo $tot;?>" id="invoicebreakdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="subbreakdown" value="" id="subbreakdown">



    <table width="95%" border="0"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="table_fullwidth">
    <tr><th width="30%">Position</th><th width="33%">Position</th>
    <th width="32%">ÇÇáãÑßÒ</th>
    </tr>

    <?php $i=1;
    while ($myrow1 = DB_fetch_array($result)) { 
     if ($i % 2==0) $bkg='td1'; else $bkg='td2';
    ?>
    <tr id="trow_<?php echo $i;?>" class="<?php echo $bkg;?> ">
    <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="cur_id_<?php echo $i;?>" id="cur_id_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['code'];?>"> <input  type="text" name="field1<?php echo $i;?>" id="field1<?php echo $i;?>" class="sel_long1 required" value="<?php echo $myrow1['depe'];?>" tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>_1" > </td>

    <td align="center"><input tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>_2" class="sel_long1 required" type="text" name="field2<?php echo $i;?>" id="field2<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['depf'] ;?>">  </td>

    <td align="center"><input tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>_4" class="sel_long1" type="text" name="field3<?php echo $i;?>" id="field3_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['depa'] ;?>"> </td>
    <td align="center"> <img src="<?php echo $site_path;?>images/del.png" width="20" class="cur" title="Delete" onclick="deleteitem('<?php echo $myrow1['code'];?>');"></td> 
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;

    }

    $breakdown = $_POST['breakdown']+$num_rows;
    $j=$num_rows+1;
    while($j<=$breakdown) {
    if ($j % 2==0) $bkg='td1'; else $bkg='td2';
     ?>




    <tr id="trow_<?php echo $j;?>" class="<?php echo $bkg;?> "><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="cur_id_<?php echo $j;?>" id="cur_id_<?php echo $j;?>" value="">
    <input  type="text" name="field1<?php echo $j;?>" id="field1<?php echo $j;?>" class="sel_long1 required" value="" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>_1" > </td>

    <td align="center" ><input  class="sel_long1 required" type="text" name="field2<?php echo $j;?>" id="field2<?php echo $j;?>" value="" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>_2"></td>

    <td align="center"><input  class="sel_long1 required" type="text" name="field3<?php echo $j;?>" id="field3<?php echo $j;?>" value="" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>_4"> </td>
    <td align="center"><img src="<?php echo $site_path;?>images/del.png" title="Delete"  onclick="delete_row_details(<?php echo $j;?>)" width="20" class="cur"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $j++; }?>
    </table>
    <div class="save_bt"><input  name="save" id="savebt" class="no_marright submit-green save_right" value="Save"  type="button" onclick="validate_save()" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>"> </div>

    <div id="did1"></div>




    <script>
     var $targets = $('#erp_from_sub').find('input, button , select'),
        steps = $targets.map(function() {
            return $(this).attr('tabindex');
        }).get();

    $('#erp_from_sub').on('keypress', 'input, button, select', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var current = $.inArray($(this).attr('tabindex'), steps),
                next = steps[++current % steps.length];
            $targets.filter('[tabindex="' + next + '"]').focus();
        }
    });

    function deleteitem(a) {
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) { document.erp_from_sub.delid.value=a;  document.getElementById('action').value='3';load_subpage('erp_from_sub');}

      }
      function delete_row_details(id)
    {
    var el = document.getElementById('trow_'+id);
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row")==true)
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    /*calculateSum_credit();*/
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: don't use capitalized  word ! .. this is like screaming in web ..

Comment: clearly whether it inserts or updates depends on the value of $cur_id. So you need to debug what is being sent to the server for that value. Presumably it's always empty, when it shouldn't be. If you can't figure it out, post the HTML form here where you try to send the value. BTW this code is horrendously vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should learn to use parameterised queries and prepared statements.

Comment: ok.. the code is updated @ADyson

Comment: @barmar can you look

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">` followed by `header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1256");`...these two lines basically do the same thing.

Comment: You seem to have removed all the code that does the update statements? Are they no longer part of your application?

Comment: oh sorry..by mistake.added

Comment: ok so, from the error messages, it can't find a field with the name cur_id1. So...when your form is created in the browser, is there any such field inside the form (you can use the View Source feature to check, or your browser's Developer Tools)? It looks like there should be, but only if `DB_fetch_array($result)` returns at least one row, thus allowing the while loop to run. Also, any chance could format your code properly with indentation? It's impossible to see the flow of control through the loops and conditional statements properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with id and also in the if else Statement. The corrected code is this.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1256");
include_once('../includes/header_config.php');
$sorting=' order by depe asc';
if (isset($_POST['field']))
{
if ($_POST['field'] != '')
{
$sorting=' order by '.$_POST['field'];
}
else
{
$sorting=' ';
}
}
?>

<?php
//delete
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']==3) ) {
$sql="delete from hr_position where code=".$_POST['delid'];
$qry = DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql="delete from listsvalues where listid=40 and id=".$_POST['delid'];
$qry = DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "delete from hrnodes  where contactid = '".$_POST['delid']."' and userid=15";
$result2= DB_query($sql,$db);
}
?>


<?php
//insert 

if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']==2) ) {
if ($_POST['invoicebreakdown']=='' || $_POST['invoicebreakdown']==0) $invoice_breakdown = 1; else $invoice_breakdown = $_POST['invoicebreakdown'];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $invoice_breakdown; $i++){

if(isset($_POST['cur_id_'.$i]) && $_POST['cur_id_'.$i]!='') $cur_id = $_POST['cur_id_'.$i]; else $cur_id ='';
// Insert the value if the cur_id is null
        if($cur_id=='') {
        $sql="select max(code) as mx from hr_position";
        $qry = DB_query($sql,$db);
        if ($res = DB_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            if ($res[0] != NULL and $res[0] > 0 ){
            $newid = $res[0] + 1;
            }else{
            $newid =1;
        }
        }       

$sql = "insert into hr_position (code,descr,lang) values (".$newid.",'".$_POST['field1'.$i]."',0)";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "insert into listsvalues (id,listid,userid,descr,lang,seq) values (".$newid.",40,-1,'".$_POST['field1'.$i]."',0,".$newid.")";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "insert into hr_position (code,descr,lang) values (".$newid.",'".$_POST['field2'.$i]."',2)";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "insert into listsvalues (id,listid,userid,descr,lang,seq) values (".$newid.",40,-1,'".$_POST['field2'.$i]."',2,".$newid.")";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "insert into hr_position (code,descr,lang) values (".$newid.",'".$_POST['field3'.$i]."',1)";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "insert into listsvalues (id,listid,userid,descr,lang,seq) values (".$newid.",40,-1,'".$_POST['field3'.$i]."',1,".$newid.")";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "select max(id) as mx from hrnodes ";
$result1= DB_query($sql,$db);
$newid1 = DB_fetch_array($result1);
$nwd = $newid1['mx']+1;
if ($_SESSION['lang']==0) {$name = $_POST['field1'.$i];} else if ($_SESSION['lang']==1) {$name = $_POST['field2'.$i];} else {$name = $_POST['field3'.$i];}
$sql = "insert into hrnodes (id,userid,title,position,parentid,contactid,acyear) VALUES 
('".$nwd."','15','".$name."','0','2','".$newid."','')";
$result2= DB_query($sql,$db);

}
else
{
$sql = "update hr_position set descr='".$_POST['field1'.$i]."' where code =".$_POST['cur_id_'.$i]." and lang = 0";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update listsvalues set descr='".$_POST['field1'.$i]."' where listid=40 and id =".$_POST['cur_id_'.$i]." and lang = 0";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);

$sql = "update hr_position set descr='".$_POST['field2'.$i]."' where code =".$_POST['cur_id_'.$i]." and lang = 1";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update listsvalues set descr='".$_POST['field2'.$i]."' where listid=40 and id =".$_POST['cur_id_'.$i]." and lang = 1";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update hr_position set descr='".$_POST['field3'.$i]."' where code =".$_POST['cur_id_'.$i]." and lang = 2";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$sql = "update listsvalues set descr='".$_POST['field3'.$i]."' where listid=40 and id  =".$_POST['cur_id_'.$i]." and lang = 2";
$result= DB_query($sql,$db);


if ($_SESSION['lang']==0) {$name = $_POST['field1'.$i];} else if ($_SESSION['lang']==1) {$name = $_POST['field2'.$i];} else {$name = $_POST['field3'.$i];}

$sql = "update hrnodes set title='".$name."' where  contactid = '".$_POST['cur_id_'.$i]."' and userid=15";
$result2= DB_query($sql,$db);
}
}
}
?>

<?php
if(!isset($_POST['breakdown'])) $_POST['breakdown']=0;
$sql = "SELECT    distinct hr_position.code, hr_position.descr AS depe, hr_position_1.descr AS depf, hr_position_2.descr AS depa
FROM         hr_position INNER JOIN
                      hr_position hr_position_1 ON hr_position.code = hr_position_1.code INNER JOIN
                      hr_position hr_position_2 ON hr_position_1.code = hr_position_2.code 
WHERE   hr_position.code<>-1 and  (hr_position.lang = 0) AND (hr_position_2.lang = 2) AND (hr_position_1.lang = 1)".$sorting;

$result= DB_query($sql,$db);
$num_rows = DB_num_rows($result);
$tot = $_POST['breakdown']+$num_rows;
?>


<input type="hidden" name="amttype" value="" id="amttype">
<input type="hidden" name="invoicebreakdown" value="<?php echo $tot;?>" id="invoicebreakdown">
<input type="hidden" name="subbreakdown" value="" id="subbreakdown">



<table width="95%" border="0"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="table_fullwidth">
<tr><th width="30%">Position</th><th width="33%">Position</th>
<th width="32%">ÇÇáãÑßÒ</th>
</tr>

<?php $i=1;
while ($myrow1 = DB_fetch_array($result)) { 
 if ($i % 2==0) $bkg='td1'; else $bkg='td2';
?>

<tr id="trow_<?php echo $i;?>" class="<?php echo $bkg;?> ">
<td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="cur_id_<?php echo $i;?>" id="cur_id_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['code'];?>"> <input  type="text" name="field1<?php echo $i;?>" id="field1<?php echo $i;?>" class="sel_long1 required" value="<?php echo $myrow1['depe'];?>" tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>_1" > </td>

<td align="center"><input tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>_2" class="sel_long1 required" type="text" name="field2<?php echo $i;?>" id="field2<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['depf'] ;?>">  </td>

<td align="center"><input tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>_4" class="sel_long1" type="text" name="field3<?php echo $i;?>" id="field3_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $myrow1['depa'] ;?>"> </td>
<td align="center"> <img src="<?php echo $site_path;?>images/del.png" width="20" class="cur" title="Delete" onclick="deleteitem('<?php echo $myrow1['code'];?>');"></td> 
</tr>
<?php
$i++;

}



$breakdown = $_POST['breakdown']+$num_rows;
$j=$num_rows+1;
while($j<=$breakdown) {
if ($j % 2==0) $bkg='td1'; else $bkg='td2';
?>




<tr id="trow_<?php echo $j;?>" class="<?php echo $bkg;?> "><td align="center">
<input type="hidden" name="cur_id_<?php echo $j;?>" id="cur_id_<?php echo $j;?>" value="">
<input  type="text" name="field1<?php echo $j;?>" id="field1<?php echo $j;?>" class="sel_long1 required" value="" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>_1" > </td>

<td align="center" ><input  class="sel_long1 required" type="text" name="field2<?php echo $j;?>" id="field2<?php echo $j;?>" value="" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>_2"></td>

<td align="center"><input  class="sel_long1 required" type="text" name="field3<?php echo $j;?>" id="field3<?php echo $j;?>" value="" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>_4"> </td>
<td align="center"><img src="<?php echo $site_path;?>images/del.png" title="Delete"  onclick="delete_row_details(<?php echo $j;?>)" width="20" class="cur"></td>
</tr>
<?php $j++; }?>
</table>
<div class="save_bt"><input  name="save" id="savebt" class="no_marright submit-green save_right" value="Save"  type="button" onclick="validate_save()" tabindex="<?php echo $j;?>"> </div>

<div id="did1"></div>




<script>
 var $targets = $('#erp_from_sub').find('input, button , select'),
    steps = $targets.map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('tabindex');
    }).get();

$('#erp_from_sub').on('keypress', 'input, button, select', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var current = $.inArray($(this).attr('tabindex'), steps),
            next = steps[++current % steps.length];
        $targets.filter('[tabindex="' + next + '"]').focus();
    }
});

function deleteitem(a) {
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) { document.erp_from_sub.delid.value=a;  document.getElementById('action').value='3';load_subpage('erp_from_sub');}

  }
  function delete_row_details(id)
{
var el = document.getElementById('trow_'+id);
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row")==true)
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
/*calculateSum_credit();*/
}
</script>
```